# Creating label with number circle and field "1v" in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, labeling, python-parser

How to create a label which combines a circle number and field "1v" in ArcMap?
For example:

[image: example the label]

I need, a line the labels. My code label expression is:

```
Function FindLabel ( [TOTAL_VIV] )  
FindLabel = "<FNT name='Arial' size='6'>"&[TOTAL_VIV]&"v"&"</FNT>"  
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using formatted labels and wingding fonts. An example is shown below:

[image: Example]

This assumes you have a field called `circle` and that this numeric field holds numbers 1 to 3, it could potentially hold 0 to 9 if you wished. Then you have another numeric field called `v` and this is the value that precedes the v.

The Label expression would be:

```vb
Function FindLabel ( [circle] , [v]  )
  dim text
  if ([circle] = 1) then
  text = "<CLR red = '255'><FNT name='Wingdings' size='18'>&#129;</FNT></CLR>" & [v] & "v"
  elseif ([circle] = 2) then
  text = "<CLR red = '255'><FNT name='Wingdings' size='18'>&#130;</FNT></CLR>" & [v] & "v"
  elseif ([circle] = 3) then
  text = "<CLR red = '255'><FNT name='Wingdings' size='18'>&#131;</FNT></CLR>" & [v] & "v"
  End If
  FindLabel =  text
End Function
```

*The only limitation with this approach is that you are limited to the Wingding fonts 0 to 10 in circles as shown in the character map below.*

[image: Character map]

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to combine the labels in this way. Your only choice is to have two copies of the same layer so you could use two different labels.

1. Create red circles with `field1` in one layer:

Layer Properties > Labels > Symbol button > Edit Symbol button > Advanced Text tab > Text Background Properties button > change type to Marker Text Background Check > select "Scale marker to fit text" + Symbol button + select Circle symbol and define color > OK button.

2. Create plain text label with `field2` in another layer.

Specify offset for the label:
Layer Properties > Labels > Symbol button > Edit Symbol button > X Offset or Y Offset

Final outlook:

[image]